# How to display binary images from Database to edit form using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, binaryfiles

I am storing images in Database as Binary Images successfully.
I want to display these images in Edit form to modify and save changes.
System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown in Edit.cshtml form while displaying Binary Images from Database.

Can someone please correct my code.

Model class:

```
public class Accommodation
    {
        [Key]
        public string A_Unique_Id { get; set; }

        public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; }

        public byte[] Picture2 { get; set; }

        public byte[] Picture3 { get; set; }


  }
```

// GET: /Accommodation/Edit/5

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        Accommodation accommodation = db.Accommodation.Find(id);
        ViewBag.SelectedAustraliaStateId = new SelectList(db.AustraliaStates, "AustraliaStateId", "AustraliaStateName", accommodation.SelectedAustraliaStateId);

        return View(accommodation);
    }
```

// POST: /Accommodation/Edit/5

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Accommodation accommodation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(accommodation).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //the following line is for re-assigning back the DDL modified value.
        accommodation.State = accommodation.SelectedAustraliaStateId;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(accommodation);
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture1)
    </div>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:** Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown at line `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To display image in your view

View

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@{
    if (Model.Picture1 != null)
      {
         string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture1);
         string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
         <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
      }
  }
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="files" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Accommodation accommodation)
{

  if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
    {
            byte[] Image;
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["files"].InputStream))
            {
                Image = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);
            }
    }
    accommodation.Picture1=Image;
  //your code to save data
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, this code is only to display the Image in edit view but when I submit the modified form, it is saving as NULL in Picture1 field. how can I save the image as well?

Comment: @Reddy are you getting the Image in your controller

Comment: both GET and  POST controllers are in the above code. Can you please check it.

Comment: Getting an error message as "system.drawing.image' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'" at line Image = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files["files"].ContentLength);

Comment: Nilesh, can you please let me know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Reddy image is not `system.drawing.image` object it is simply a variable check edited answer

Comment: HI Nilesh, thanks for correction. It is still inserting NULL values in the images fields after edit and save.  "files" is not coming from database right? I need to retrieve the existing binary image from Database and update the same image instead of adding as NULL

Comment: @Reddy yes during edit you have to check if image is not present then dont update else update the field in db

Comment: I am not a experienced developer but trying to implement a small solution. Can you please let me know where do I have check if image is not present then dont update else update the field in db

Comment: @Nilesh its not work for me accommodation  use byte[] but sended values are httppostedfilebase , i think i should create custom ByteArrayModelBinder

Comment: @AminM can you share your code to get more clarification

Comment: @Nilesh   my code is similar but after click edit and choose new image it sended back to actionmethod as HttpPostedFileBase but beacuse model is byte array it throw 'mvc upload image The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters'  here is my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/v1FnN9

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);

string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteData);

string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64{0}",imageBase64Data);

Session["photo"] = imageDataURL;
```

In _layout.cshtml page add this line.